# Running Node from Powershell after a file has been added to a folder

Tags: node.js, powershell

Currently I have code set-up in Powershell that will run my NodeJS code if a file is added into a destination folder. Both parts are working separately: Powershell logs when a file is being added, and the NodeJS is working when run in Powershell with the command node filepath, but when put together the event is not triggering my NodeJS code to run. I'm pretty new to Powershell so any help would be appreciated! Below is my code.

```
$folder = 'M:\Operational Sales Plan\Import' #  path to monitor
 
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'} 
 
 
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
node C:\Users\lwest\Desktop\Scripts\import-csv\index.js
& $PSScriptRoot\RunPopulateOperationalPlan.ps1
}
```

Comment: Can you show us ur nodejs code?

Comment: What is your `$filter`?

Comment: For me your code works if I remove `, $filter` from the line with `New-Object`. Maybe set the `$filter` in the next line instead: `$fsw.Filter = $filter`